# Build chrome extension to tweet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter

I'm trying to build a simple chrome extension which consists of one icon that when clicked, pops up the official twitter window (as in [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)). The problem with most extensions that do this is that the window remains open after. If, however, you include [this script](http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) provided by Twitter , they take care of closing the window after a few seconds, and that is what I want to do, so I'm trying to inject that code and then executing the URL. (Keep in mind both my javascript and chrome extensions knowledge is very limited).

This is what I have so far.

```
function onClicked(tab) {
        var twitterWidgets = document.createElement("script");
        twitterWidgets.type = "text/javascript";
        twitterWidgets.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        head.appendChild(twitterWidgets);

        var urlToTweet = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?"
    + "text=" + encodeURIComponent(tab.title)
    + "&url=" + encodeURIComponent(tab.url);

        //window.open(urlToTweet);
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(onClicked);
```

*window.open* is no good, as it opens a new tab. Neither is *window.location* and variants, that don't even seem to work at all. I realise I may have to add some *chrome.extension.getURL* to *twitterWidgets.src*, or something like it, but at this point, the more I mess with the script, the more confused I get.

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know if any of these work, but worth a try: chrome.window.create (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create), or perhaps the "default_popup" property in the manifest file (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#manifest) will let you set the html page to the url of the intent (I doubt it lets you do that though).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really as to what your trying to do but if you use window.open like this it will open in the same page.

```
window.open("http://www.insertUrlHere.com","_self")
```

Hope this helps and is simple enough

Comment: I am (was) trying to open the twitter intents window (a separate one), and have it close automatically after sending the tweet.